# How much text a label can adopt

Tags: ios, iphone

In my project there is a specific requirement, When `UILabel`'s text gets truncated I need to give view more functionality. Initially there will be a `CGRect` given. Accordingly we need to show the label if text truncated we need to at the end of label **...View more** text should be shown. Upon tapping on **...View more** view more I need to make my label bigger. So I m doing

```
NSMutableString *truncatedString = [text mutableCopy];
[truncatedString appendString:ellipsis];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(truncatedString.length - (ellipsis.length + 1), 1);
do {
    [truncatedString deleteCharactersInRange:range];
    range.location--;
    [self setText:truncatedString];
} while ([self isTextTruncated]);
```

it works fine for smaller text since I m using it for `UITableViewCell`. It is lagging for bigger texts since above operation happens for every time. So I want to know the text that is adopted in `UILabel` so that I can do any operation with new text. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: 
I have a label and bigger text. say my text is

"Apple Inc. is an American multinational corporation headquartered in Cupertino, California, that designs, develops, and sells consumer electronics, computer software, online services, and personal computers." if my label would adopt only  "Apple Inc. is an American multinational corporation.." I need this text alone

Answer (score 3):

Use this method to calculate `height` that would be required for the text to get fit into the provided `UILabel`:

```
- (CGFloat)getLabelHeight:(UILabel*)label
{
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, 20000.0f);
    CGSize size;

    NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
    CGSize boundingBox = [yourString boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}
                                                  context:context].size;

    size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height));

    return size.height;
}
```

Compare the returned height with height of your label:

```
CGFloat heightRequired = [self getLabelHeight:myLabel];
if(myLabel.frame.size.height < heightRequired) {
    //you need to show more because the text is more than the label width and height.
}
else {
    //you don't need to show more because the text is not more than the label width and height.
}
```

**EDIT:** The purpose of comparing height is to check whether frame is enough to show text or not. So, even if you want to increase the width of label to show more text, it will give you desired result.

Comment: I don't need the height. Even i do the same I want a text (NSString) that is apt with UILabel

Comment: Check the edited post. use your text string in replacement of 'yourString'

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate size of text as bellow and if returned size is bigger than text field size than you need to show ...View more

```
CGSize requiredSize = [text sizeWithFont:withFont constrainedToSize:textViewSize lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't find an answer, i recommend this workaround:

By trying using a text with known length, get the max number of characters that the label fits,and use that value to do the following:

```
int maxNumOfChar = 15; //For example
if (text.length > maxNumOfChar){
NSString* viewMore = @"...View More";
    text = [[text substringToIndex:maxNumOfChar - [viewMore length]] stringByAppendingString: viewMore];
}
```